# Capture a part of some application, for example, via XPath and show it on secondary display

Tags: java, android

I have already installed navigation app in my car (Android).

I want to write some background app, that will capture a video of a part of the navi application (via XPath) and simultaneously show it on secondary display #1 (HUD).

How to do it for example with MediaProjection API?